# Proof of Borel isomorphism theorem by Rao and Srivastava

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Does someone know how Rao and Srivastava proved the Borel isomorphism theorem in their paper "An elementary proof of the Borel isomorphism theorem" published in 1995?

I can't find anywhere this paper, neither a book or a pdf providing a proof, or even sketching it. Do you know a reference for that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The proof can be found in the book *A Course on Borel Sets* by Srivastava. The proof relies on a measurable version of the the Cantor-Bernstein theorem.

Comment: I discovered this book with your comment, and it's a good book. Thank you !